# why nodeNames are different?

Tags: javascript, dom

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1u12x9b/):

```
<p id="para-01"><span>First span</span></p>
<p id="para-02">
  <span>Second span</span>
</p>
```

The two paragraphs are nearly the same except the new lines. Why nodeNames are `SPAN` and `#text`?

Comment: Line break in `#para-02` creates a hidden DOM node named `#text`

Comment: /n is the first child and it #text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text is a type of node too! Here’s some HTML:

```html
<p>hello <span>world</span></p>
```

and its corresponding tree:

```
Element p
    Text "hello "
    Element span
        Text "world"
```

Whitespace – here, the newline and two spaces – still makes a text node, and your second `<p>`’s first child is this whitespace-only text node.

You can get the first element child in modern browsers with the `firstElementChild` property [(updated fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/u1u12x9b/1/):

```
console.log(document.getElementById('para-02').firstElementChild.nodeName)
```

and in all browsers with the `children` collection, which only contains elements*:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('para-02').children[0].nodeName)
```

<sub>* plus comments in IE8 and earlier</sub>